# button('reset')

Tags: jquery

The following Single Page Application (created by someone else) which authenticates users,  http://backbonedevise.herokuapp.com was created using Backbonejs and a plugin called Marionette. I am trying to rewrite it without Marionnette. The success and error callbacks have this line of code

```
el.find('input.btn-primary').button('reset');
```

Prior to the login the html looks like this

```
 <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary">
```

In other words, it doesn't have a type reset.  I'm assuming the line `el.find('input.btn-primary').button('reset');` somehow resets the button. I tried to rewrite it this way

```
$('input.btn-primary').button('reset');
```

but I received an error,

```
Object has no method button.
```

Can you explain what I might be doing wrong and how i might fix it.

The success callback.

```
this.model.save(this.model.attributes, {
      success: function(userSession, response) {
        el.find('form').prepend(BD.Helpers.Notifications.success("Instructions for resetting your password have been sent. Please check your email for further instructions."));
        el.find('input.btn-primary').button('reset');
      },
```

Comment: Where does the `button()` method come from? That's probably the method you need to reimplement

Comment: I'm with @JuanMendes on this one. I can't find any reference to that script snippet you're referring, not even with Firebug's full text search across all loaded script files.

Comment: `.button()` is implemented as part of Marionette.  If you unpack the .js file sourced at the top of the linked site, Marionette is packed in directly with jQuery.

Comment: @rockerest Do you know where we can find this Marionette plugin? The one I found ([Backbone Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/)) doesn't have such a `button` method.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens I have no idea.  I searched through Marionette's entire github history and the source never has a `.button()` implemented.  Maybe this is a custom clone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marionette implements a `.button()` method in it's internals.

It's likely that `.button()` is a hook to easily manage button states, but I didn't dig too far into it (I don't know anything about Marionette).

Here's the instance in Marionette where `.button` is defined, although there are plenty of places that reference it that I found:

```
a.fn.button = function (c) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var d = a(this),
                e = d.data("button"),
                f = typeof c == "object" && c;
            e || d.data("button", e = new b(this, f)), c == "toggle" ? e.toggle() : c && e.setState(c)
        })
```

What it boils down to is that either you need to figure out what `.button()` does for you in Marionette and re-implement it yourself, or do without it entirely.

For what it's worth, jQuery UI has a `.button` method, too, so since you're still using jQuery, you could plug that in.

Comment: +1 because you took the time to format minified code. It's still not very understandable, but at least it's readable.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to google a marionette button method but found nada.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks, I cheated and used [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to parse it for me!

Comment: @rockerest, that hardly qualifies as cheating. That's minified code we're talking about :)